# BeanShell Assertion in jdbc request for JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

Getting two columns from a jdbc sampler  i.e ID and WF. Trying to fail it, if it exceeds than the predefined variables by using beanshell.
Below is the sample code.

```
String myValue1 = vars.get("WF_1");
String myValue2 = vars.get("WF_2");
if(!myValue1.equals ("3")){
  log.info("myValue1 =" + myValue1);
  Failure = true;
  FailureMessage = " The database value should be " + myValue1 + ".";
}
else if(!myValue2.equals ("5")){
  //log something
  Failure = true;
  log.info("myValue2 =" + myValue2);
   FailureMessage = " The database value should be " + myValue2 + ".";

else {
  //can be log something?
     Failure = false;

}
```

Above code is working when I know the number of rows for a particular column. If the rows values are dynamic and increasing or decreasing according to sysdate than how to compare them with the predefined and fail the sampler.